# Как получить значение итератора по ключу?

Tags: php

Есть функция, возвращающая генератор-словарь. Например такая:

```
function foo() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        yield "key-$i" => $i * 3;
}
```

Просто так обратиться как к массиву по ключу не выходит: `$item = foo()['key-1'];`

Можно конечно сконвертировать ее в массив с помощью `iterator_to_array`, но это не очень экономично. Хочется что-то вроде:

```
function get_iterator_item($it, $key) {
    foreach ($it as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $key)
            return $v;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Есть что-то такое стандартное?

Comment: Не экономично то, что написали вы, функция `iterator_to_array` работает гораздо быстрее и продуктивнее.

Comment: `iterator_to_array`: 1.001358  
`get_iterator_item`: 4.053115

Comment: А теперь оборвите на пятом при генераторе на миллион ? :)

Comment: Вот вот. @And вы на чем тестировали то? Очевидно же что чем больше будет данных тем более заметным будет выигрыш моей функции в скорости, по сравнению с тем чтобы все данные в массив конвертировать. А если я из базы читаю и там гигабайты данных? Они же в память не влезут!

Comment: @splash58, все равно проигрывает: `iterator_to_array`: 0.160762 `get_iterator_item`: 0.186655

Comment: @And код бенчмарка в студию

Comment: @Dark Byte, сделай себе и проверь. Учитывая, что это складывается в массив. конечно же, а иначе понту от вашей функции и генератора. когда решить можно одним циклом `for`?

Comment: @And разумеется оно никуда не складывается. Я же сказал - данных могут быть гигабайты. Они не влезут в оперативную память. У меня так уже было. Поэтому я всегда где возможно пихаю генераторы. А функция нужна чтобы не писать везде цикл для этого. Переиспользование кода - DRY, не слышал?

Comment: @DarkByte, Эм - гигабайты. Странный тогда алгоритм работы с файловой системой. Вы тогда аж в 3-не или в 4-не, затормаживаете процесс. раз вы читаете файлы, то тогда лучше воспользоваться считыванием по строчно, со смещением, а не каждый раз с нуля.

Comment: @And я не считываю файлы, я считываю данные из базы. И да я читаю блоками по N записей.

Answer (score -2):

Начнем с того, что `yield` возвращает `object` и обратиться по ключу, как хотите вы, не получится.
Точнее получится, но не так - для этого есть специальная функция конвертирования `iterator_to_array`.

```
function foo() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        yield "key-$i" => $i * 3;
    }
}

$array = iterator_to_array(foo());

var_dump($array);
```

Вывод:

```
array(10) {
  ["key-0"]=>
  int(0)
  ["key-1"]=>
  int(3)
  ["key-2"]=>
  int(6)
  ["key-3"]=>
  int(9)
  ["key-4"]=>
  int(12)
  ["key-5"]=>
  int(15)
  ["key-6"]=>
  int(18)
  ["key-7"]=>
  int(21)
  ["key-8"]=>
  int(24)
  ["key-9"]=>
  int(27)
}
```

Теперь можно обратиться по ключу.

Comment: Т.е. вы взяли то что я написал и выдали это за свой ответ?